# How to add X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET header when sending emails using Amazon SES from Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using the following header setting to enable tracking of clicks, opens, bounces, etc. for my transactional emails through [`Amazon SES`](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) service:

```
X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: ConfiguregationSetName
```

I can add it via a server side script to the outgoing mail (via PHP).

The question is how do I add it in Microsoft Outlook when sending mail there? (I'm talking about me sending those emails manually.)

Comment: I found a solution: https://dennisbabkin.com/olh/

Answer (score 0):

As I know, I'm afraid that we could not modify message header on our own when sending emails in Outlook client.